# How add a classic start menu in Ubuntu 15?

Tags: menu

How add a classic start menu in Ubuntu 15? Like the LinuxMint start menu.

Comment: What do you mean by "Classic Start Menu", do you mean the old style menus like before Unity?

Comment: Use the Cinnamon DE if you want the look of Mint

Comment: Thomas W, yes. and I want add a menu in ubuntu without install cinnamon

Answer (score 0):

[Cinnamon](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/) is lightweight desktop environment for UNIX-like operating systems, it provides advanced modern features on top of a traditional desktop layout.

Just like Linux Mint, it aims to be easy to use, powerful and flexible.

**Install**

Launch terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and run these command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:moorkai/cinnamon

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

Cinnamon desktop interface
[image: Source: Ubuntu Handbook]

Comment: I want add a menu in ubuntu without install cinnamon

Comment: Give a try to [ClassicMenuIndicator](http://www.howtogeek.com/189929/how-to-install-and-launch-the-classic-gnome-menu-in-ubuntu-14.04/)

Comment: Thank you for the CLassicMenuIndicator http://www.howtogeek.com/189929/how-to-install-and-launch-the-classic-gnome-menu-in-ubuntu-14.04/